# How to stop jQuery tabs CSS from being overwritten

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I have a WordPress plugin that is a jQuery tabbed interface that sits in the WordPress theme sidebar.
On 90% of sites the plugin displays as it is supposed to however on 10% of sites the jQuery tabs navigation tabs CSS styles are messed up and overwritten by another plugin or the theme CSS file.

This is a fragment of how the tabs are displayed:

```
<div id="aaw_tabs" style="width:250px !important">

    <ul class="aaw_tabnav">
        <li><a href="#aaw-tabs-popular">Popular</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aaw-tabs-recent">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aaw-tabs-comments">Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aaw-tabs-tags">Tags</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="aaw_tabs_body">

        <div class="inside">

            <div id="aaw-tabs-popular">
                example tab content
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="aaw-tabs-recent">
                example tab content
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="aaw-tabs-comments">
                example tab content
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div> 

            <div id="aaw-tabs-tags">
                example tab content
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I initialize the jQuery tabs with this jQuery code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {

        // Advanced Activity Widget Tabs
        $( "#aaw_tabs" ).tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 200 } });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And here it the CSS that styles the tabs:

```
#aaw_tabs { padding:0 !important; margin:0 auto !important; border:none !important; background:none !important}

ul.aaw_tabnav { position:relative; margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important; list-style-type:none !important; width:100%; }
ul.aaw_tabnav li { display:inline; padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; border:none !important; background:none !important;  }

ul.aaw_tabnav li a { text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase; color:#444; padding:5px; outline:none; font-size:0.8em; font-weight:bold; background:#DDD; border-bottom:none; border-top:1px solid #DDD; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF; -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; border-radius:5px 5px 0 0; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD, #CCCCCC); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #DDDDDD), color-stop(1, #CCCCCC)); -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#DDDDDD', EndColorStr='#CCCCCC')"; /* IE8 only */ filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#DDDDDD', EndColorStr='#CCCCCC'); /* IE6,IE7 only */}
ul.aaw_tabnav li a:hover { color:#FFF; background:#666; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ccc; }
ul.aaw_tabnav li a:active, ul.aaw_tabnav li.ui-tabs-selected a { text-decoration:none; padding:5px; color:#666; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF; border:1px solid #CCC; border-top-color:#DDD; border-bottom:none; top:1px; background:#EAEAEA; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EAEAEA); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #EAEAEA)); -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#EAEAEA')"; /* IE8 only */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#EAEAEA'); /* IE6,IE7 only */}

.aaw_tabs_body { width:98% !important; padding:1%; background:#EAEAEA; border:1px solid #CCC; -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px; -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px; border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px; }
.aaw_tab_single_box { float:left; width:96%; padding:2%; background:#FEFEFE url(../images/bg-box.png) repeat-x; border:1px solid #CCC; display:none; }

.aww_tabs_body .inside { margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important }
.aaw_tabs_body .inside ul { margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important}
.aaw_tabs_body .inside ul li { border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5 !important; float:left; display:inline; font-size:11px !important; color:#595959 !important; margin:0px 1px 0px 0px !important; padding:10px 0px 5px 5px !important; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:none; vertical-align:top !important; width:260px; }
.aaw_tabs_body .inside ul li a { display:block; float:left; padding:0px 7px 10px; color:#595959 !important; font:inherit 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; text-decoration:none !important }
.aaw_tabs_body .inside ul li a:hover { text-decoration:none !important; color:#0088CC !important }

.clear { clear:left;}
.ui-tabs-hide { display:none; }
```

Now what the issue is. There are four tabs for the navigation. This is what they should look like:

[image: Working tab navigation]

However on some site the tab navigation is messed up and the tab navigation is distorted and looks like this:

[image: Distorted tabs]

This site is from a European site so the text is displayed on the right which is fine however the tab navigation seems to span the full width.

I am sure it has to do with the CSS styling of the tabs but I can't work it out.

It is the CSS class .aaw_tabs that styles the navigation. They are currently styled as display:inline. I have tried float, display:inline-block.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have trying to figure this issue out for some months now.

Thanks

Comment: Can you link us to the site please?

Comment: The working site is http://www.wpinsite.com. The non working site is: http://www.xn--4dbcyzi5a.com/%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%A8/

Comment: It is not just this one client site it doesn't work on. I have had a few people state the same problem. On the majority though it works fine.

Comment: On the broken site, those are not the same CSS files. On the working site, you have display:inline-block, on the non working, you have display:inline, which needs to be display:inline-block;. Then you have an unclosed `<li>` tag which causes the layout to break all together when you click on a tab. Fix those two issues and you're good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable input. I will fix those issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the css selectors that you think that are getting overwritten, and then change the selectors name. Then add some js into the plugin that checks if the selector already exists in the loaded css files --> then the secondary selector that you duplicated in the first step can add the css values to the plugin.

Or a simpler solution, rename the selectors with really weird ( just names that are not common ) names so there is no chance they  will be duplicated and then comment what each selector does in the css file.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eri. I think it has more to do with the WordPress .sidebar and .widget CSS classes that are added to widgets.